# ASP.NET Web API HTTP GET with optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Writing my first ASP.NET Web API web service. Still learing the power of Linq as well. I feel like there is a more ideomatic way of doing this:

```
public class StylesController : ApiController
{
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    // GET api/Styles
    public IEnumerable<Style> GetStyles(int division = 0, int family = 0, int model = 0, int year = 0, string market = "ANY")
    {
        market = market.ToUpper(); // make sure market is upper case

        IEnumerable<Style> q = db.Styles;

        if (division > 0) { q = q.Where(s => s.DivisionId == division); }
        if (family > 0) { q = q.Where(s => s.FamilyId == family); }
        if (model > 0) { q = q.Where(s => s.ModelId == model); }
        if (year > 0) { q = q.Where(s => s.Year == year); }
        if (market != "ANY") { q = q.Where(s => s.MarketCode == market); }

        return q.Distinct().OrderBy(s => s.Id).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see of this code, you are doing an AND operation.  i.e. division = 1 AND year = 2012.  Am I correct?

Comment: Correct, but each part of the AND is optional.

Comment: Fine to return an IEnumerable but that first declaration should be IQueryable<Style> q =

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good layout and white space.

Although the logic works, I think it is very confusing, and not overly obvious.  At first glance, it the if statements are very confusing.  I would also rename the variables to have an Id or Code to the end of them to keep naming consistent.

I think this is a good place where you could incorporate the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

```
public class StylesController : ApiController
{
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    public IEnumerable<Style> GetStyles(int divisionId = 0, int familyId = 0, int modelId = 0, int year = 0, string marketCode = "ANY")
    {
        var divisionIsAMatch = new DivisionIsAMatchSpecification(divisionId);
        var familyIsAMatch = new FamilyIsAMatchSpecification(familyId);
        var modelIsAMatch = new ModelIsAMatchSpecification(modelId);
        var yearIsAMatch = new YearIsAMatchSpecification(year);
        var marketIsAMatch = new MarketIsAMatchSpecification(marketCode);

        var q = db.Styles

        return q.Where(
                divisionIsAMatch
                .And(familyIsAMatch)
                .And(modelIsAMatch)
                .And(yearIsAMatch)
                .And(marketIsAMatch).IsSatisfiedBy
            ).Distinct()
           .OrderBy(s => s.Id);
    }
}
```

Where

```
internal class DivisionIsAMatchSpecification : Specification<Style>
{
    private readonly int _divisionId;

    public DivisionIsAMatchSpecification(int divisionId)
    {
        _divisionId = divisionId;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Style style)
    {
        if (_divisionId == 0) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return style.DivisionId == _divisionId;
    }
}
```

Just rinse and repeat for each of the specifications you need.  Of course, you will have to create the base classes for them too.

I haven't tested this, but I have used this pattern before, and it works really nicely.

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but I'm not happy with this approach. I'm not sure how that should be translated to database statements using LINQ.